# Does OSX have a hidden "Device Manager" list like Windows?

Tags: system-information

Back in the Windows world there was a Device Manager control panel that would list all the devices that were connected to your computer.

There was even an option to show "hidden devices", basically a list of items like thumb-drives, SD cards, etc. that were once connected to your PC.

I'm just curious if something like this exists in OSX? Is there a list of devices that are connected or ever were connected?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Search for `System Information` in Lion or later (or `System Profiler` in Snow Leopard and earlier versions of Mac OS) in Spotlight (press <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>).

The program is in /Applications/Utilities and is the tool to see the connected USB devices and other hardware details. It is quite simliar to `Device Manager` on Windows.

Alternatively you can access it via the Apple Menu

`` -> `About This Mac` -> `More Info...` -> `System Report...`

[image: System Information]

The System Information can save system profiler information to a file, so you could review an older snapshot to see what was connected once, but the Mac OS doesn't record all the devices connected - just the ones actually connected when you run the tool and it scans the current items on the device tree.

Comment: +1, BUT: System Profiler does NOT offer you any option to change device settings.

Comment: remark: this instructions are correct for osx 10.7. On 10.6 and before its called: System Profiler

Comment: Thanks! And it's good to know that OSX doesn't record all the connected devices. That was one _feature_ that annoyed me in Windows because I would become so OCD that I would periodically go in and delete/cleanup the unused invisible items!

Comment: the profiler just only shows the report you can't configure or reinstall your device or drivers

Comment: remark: in Mavericks (10.9) and above, the `More Info...` button is now labelled `System Report...`.

Comment: Still wondering if is possible to manage (not only list, like the System Information do) my USB devices, like turning off the trackpad USB.

Comment: Use Command+R to refresh the list of connected devices